# How does DateTime.Now affect query plan caching in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, caching, sql-execution-plan

**Question:**

Does passing `DateTime.Now` as a parameter to a proc prevent SQL Server from caching the query plan?  If so, then is the web app missing out on huge performance gains?

**Possible Solution:**

I thought `DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)` would be a possible solution. It would pass the same end-date to the sql proc (per day). And the user would still get the latest data. Please speak to this as well.

**Given Example:**

Let's say we have a stored procedure. It reports data back to a user on a webpage.  The user can set a date range.  If the user sets today's date as the "end date," which includes today's data, the web app passes `DateTime.Now` to the sql proc.

Let's say that one user runs a report--`5/1/2010` to `now`--over and over several times.  On the webpage, the user sees `5/1/2010` to `5/4/2010`.  But the web app passes `DateTime.Now` to the sql proc as the end date.  So, the end date in the proc will always be different, although the user is querying a similar date range.

Assume the number of records in the table and number of users are large. So any performance gains matter.  Hence the importance of the question.

**Example proc and execution (if that helps to understand):**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetFooData
    @StartDate datetime
    @EndDate datetime
AS

    SELECT *
    FROM Foo
    WHERE LogDate >= @StartDate
    AND LogDate < @EndDate
```

Here's a sample execution using DateTime.Now:

```
EXEC GetFooData '2010-05-01', '2010-05-04 15:41:27' -- passed in DateTime.Now
```

Here's a sample execution using DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)

```
EXEC GetFooData '2010-05-01', '2010-05-05' -- passed in DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)
```

The same data is returned for both procs, since the current time is: `2010-05-04 15:41:27`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you invoke a stored procedure, not directly a query, then your only query that changes is the actual batch you send to SQL, the `EXEC GetFooData '2010-05-01', '2010-05-05'` vs. `GetFooData '2010-05-01', '2010-05-04 15:41:27'`. This is a trivial batch, that will generate a trivial plan. While is true that, from a strict technical point of view, you are loosing some performance, it will be all but unmeasurable. The details why this happes are explained in this response: [Dynamically created SQL vs Parameters in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608522/dynamically-created-sql-vs-parameters-in-sql-server/1608856#1608856)

The good news is that by a minor change in your SqlClient invocation code, you'll benefit from even that minor performance improvement mentioned there. Change your SqlCommand code to be an explicit stored procedure invocation:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetFooData", connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", dateFrom);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", DateTime.Now);
```

As a side note, storing localized times in the database is not a very good idea, due to the clients being on different time zones than the server and due to the complications of daylight savings change night. A much better solution is to *always* store UTC time and simply format it to user's local time in the application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Remus.  The real sql query I'm dealing with is complex; it involves multiple joined tables and `where` clauses.  Might the performance gain be non-trivial then?

Comment: Possibly. You can run the query in an SSMS Query Window after you run `SET STATISTICS TIME ON`. This will print out the query compile time, which would be the time you *may* save. There are also various performance counters that may help you make a decissions, see http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlprogrammability/archive/2007/01/19/12-0-plan-cache-trace-events-and-performance-counters.aspx. Note that SQL Server does a pretty good job at auto-parameterizing the query, but nothing beats passing in exactly the same text every time and using @parameters.

Answer (score 6):

The query plan will be cached regardless of parameter values. Parameters basically *guarantee* that a consistent, reusable query exists, since they are type-safe as far as SQL server is concerned.

What you want is not query plan, but result caching. And this will be affected by the behavior you describe.

Since you seem to handle whole days only, you can try passing in dates, not datetimes, to minimize different parameter values. Also try caching query results in the application instead of doing a database roundtrip every time.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you are probably fine if the second parameter is just drifting upward in real time.

However, it is possible to become a victim of [parameter sniffing](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=parameter+sniffing) where the first execution (which produces the cached execution plan) is called with parameters which produce a plan which is not typically good for the other parameters normally used (or the data profile changes drastically).  The later invocations might use a plan which is sometimes so poor that it won't even complete properly.

If your data profile changes drastically by different choices of parameters, and the execution plan becomes poor for certain choices of parameters, you can mask the parameters into local variables - this will effectively prevent parameter sniffing in SQL Server 2005.  There is also the WITH RECOMPILE (either in the SP or in the EXEC - but for heavily called SPs, this is not a viable option)  In SQL Server 2008, I would almost always use the OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN which will avoid producing a plan based on parameter sniffing.