# How to search for a date less than or greater than X

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

This is the code I'm using to create a custom report that filters by a date range. The first criteria works fine, however the second and third do not. It throws a syntax error. Can anyone tell me why?

```
string cmd = "SELECT PURCHASE_ORDER.cid, PURCHASE_ORDER.deptid, PURCHASE_ORDER.procid, PURCHASE_ORDER.purchase_order_no, PURCHASE_ORDER.requesition_no, PURCHASE_ORDER.contract_no, PURCHASE_ORDER.purchase_order_date, COMPANY.company_name,  DEPARTMENT.department_name, PROCUREMENT_METH.method FROM PURCHASE_ORDER INNER JOIN PROCUREMENT_METH ON PURCHASE_ORDER.procid = PROCUREMENT_METH.procid INNER JOIN COMPANY ON PURCHASE_ORDER.cid = COMPANY.cid INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT ON PURCHASE_ORDER.deptid = DEPARTMENT.deptid WHERE PURCHASE_ORDER.deptid = DEPARTMENT.deptid";

// Check Criteras
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ddlDepartment.Text) && !ddlDepartment.Text.Equals("0"))
   cmd += " AND PURCHASE_ORDER.deptid LIKE '%" + ddlDepartment.Text + "%' ";

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtfromdate.Text))
   cmd += "AND PURCHASE_ORDER.purchase_order_date '<" + txtfromdate.Text + "' ";

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txttodate.Text))
   cmd += "AND PURCHASE_ORDER.purchase_order_date '<" + txttodate.Text + "' ";
```

Comment: You need to parse the contents of the textbox using `DateTime.Parse`, ideally `DateTime.TryParse` to validate input.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I am using a calendar control.

Answer (score 4):

It really helps to actually read through your generated SQL, and actually read the syntax error messages.

Let's say `txttodate.Text` gives the value "25-Jul-2014".  Here's what your code generates for that:

```
AND PURCHASE_ORDER.purchase_order_date '<25-Jul-2014'
```

And the error message SQL Server generates in that situation:

> Error 102: Incorrect syntax near '<25-Jul-2014'.

That's because your `<` is inside the string.  Try this way instead, it'll work *much* better:

```
cmd += "AND PURCHASE_ORDER.purchase_order_date < '" + txttodate.Text + "' ";
```

---

And while we're on the topic of making this better, use [parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608522/dynamically-created-sql-vs-parameters-in-sql-server).

Comment: That is correct. I fixed it in my answer. Thank you

Comment: @vt146911 In general, unless you're embarking on a teaching exercise, you don't answer your own questions.  If there's an answer that's correct, accept that answer.

Comment: I did not see your answers until I submitted mine.

Answer (score 2):

If your `purchase_order_date` database field is of type `DATETIME` then you will need to parse the contents of the textbox into a C# Date object and then `ToString()` the Date object to the SQL standard date format.

**Rudimentary:**

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(txttodate.Text.Trim().Replace("'","''"));
cmd += "AND PURCHASE_ORDER.purchase_order_date '<" + datetime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' ";
```

**Better:**

```
DateTime dateTime,dateTime2;

if (DateTime.TryParse(txttodate.Text.Trim().Replace("'","''"), out dateTime1) && DateTime.TryParse(txtfromdate.Text.Trim().Replace("'","''"), out dateTime2))
{
    cmd += "AND PURCHASE_ORDER.purchase_order_date BETWEEN + '" + dateTime1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' AND '" + dateTime2.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
}
```

Also I think you are probably looking to use the `BETWEEN` SQL operator to determine any `purchase_order_dates` between the FROM date and the TO date.

Comment: That would work as well. But in my case it is fine. Is just the statement was not spaced that is why it kept failing. Sorry about that

Comment: @vt146911 You are opening yourself up to all kinds of dangers by not validating user input (yes including those inputted through the calendar control)

Comment: Simply use parametrized queries... While your suggestion is marginally better than original code it still bad idea.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I am aware of that - but I know he isn't going to implement parameterized queries so a hackjob solution will be better than nothing ;)

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it. the problem was a space after

```
cmd += "AND PURCHASE_ORDER.purchase_order_date '<" + txtfromdate.Text + "'
```

like this:

```
cmd += " AND PURCHASE_ORDER.purchase_order_date <'" + txtfromdate.Text + "'
```

Comment: I would put a trailing space on the first line, and remove the leading space from the filter lines.

Comment: Where you put your spaces doesn't make any difference.  The problem was that you were putting the operator inside the string.

Comment: -1: This is not very good suggestion - please don't follow it. Use parametrized queries instead.